# Is it possible to enable keyboard navigation in PrimeNg ContextMenu?

Tags: angular, contextmenu, primeng

I'm building a Angular 4 site using PrimeNg. Does anybody know if it's possible to implement keyboard navigation in the contextmenu. Any ideas on how?

Answer (score 1):

It is not supported at the moment.

You can create an issue from here

https://github.com/primefaces/primeng

Answer (score -1):

you could capture keyboard and set some css styles to emulate focus

```
@Component({
  ....
  host: {'(document:keydown)': 'handleKeyboardEvents($event)'}
})


  private handleKeyboardEvents(event: KeyboardEvent) {
    if (event.keyCode === 40 && MenuPressed) {//down
      //implement here your logic
```